# Missing LetsEncrypt httpd-prefix.conf File

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, lets-encrypt

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with a missing config file for LetsEncrypt. Is there a source to find it? Or is it automatically generated? I'm trying to update to a new ssl cert, but can't restart apache2 because it won't restart until it finds that certificate. Every time I try to restart, I keep getting this error:

```
httpd.bin: Syntax error on line 544 of /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 46 of /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf: Syntax error on lin
e 2 of /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf: Could not open configuration file /opt/bitnami/apps/letsencrypt/conf/httpd-prefix.conf: No such file or 
directory
apache config test fails, aborting
```

If it helps, I'm on a AWS Lightsail instance.

Comment: Are you running WordPress by any chance?

Comment: Can you give more details about how you got here? Did it happen out of nowhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you need is one of the standard Bitnami configuration files, described [in their documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/infrastructure/lamp/configuration/configure-custom-application/):

> The httpd-prefix.conf file ships the default configuration for the
> applications in “prefix” mode, such that the application can be accessed
> at (for example) http://example.com/myapp.
>
> ```
>  Alias /myapp/ "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs/"
>  Alias /myapp "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs"
>
>  Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf"
> ```

You can reconstruct the file from your existing configuration. The httpd-app.conf, if you have lost it also, contains the location and access of the website:

```
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs">
      Options +MultiViews
      AllowOverride None
      <IfVersion < 2.3 >
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      </IfVersion>
      <IfVersion >= 2.3>
      Require all granted
      </IfVersion>
  </Directory>

  Include /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/htaccess.conf
```

and for a public website, I'd think htaccess would be likely empty, so you can even comment that line out.

If you have other sites on that machine, you can check *their* config to have an idea of how to rebuild the missing one. I've done this many times.

As a last resort, **recreate an empty site** from a Bitnami image of the same version, using the same parameters. You needn't install it for real. Just grab the Apache configuration files, then use them as a template for your installation.

Otherwise, **but this is gross butchery**, you can try recovering the configuration *from the running Apache instance* using [this answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/733961/is-there-a-command-to-get-apache-to-display-its-running-config-from-memory). You will then have to grep the resulting file to locate the missing parts, and store them in the appropriate files. If you go down this road, be aware that it is a mess.